# Converting xml request to java pojo class having nested tags

Tags: xml, pojo

I have an xml as given below

```
<deliver>
<oa><number>57500</number></oa>
<da><number>+35314370969</number></da>
<ud>Message Text</ud>
</deliver>
```

How can i convert it into java pojo object to map to @RequestBody

Comment: Can someone please tell me how to map to request body as it has 2 tags <oa><number> I am able to do it for one tag

Comment: Use XPath and just get the values needed.  For example /oa/number or da/number.  No need for custom object to just pick out a couple values.